# Bar chart goes below zero line ios-charts

Tags: swift, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I have following question, today i updated the 'charts' pod in my project and suddenly the chart is drawn wrong. I mean the bars are going below zero, and not starting at the zero line.

[image: Wrong barchart]

and before the update it looked like this:

[image: before chart]

(i know the second image is a grouped barchart)
but my problem is that in the new version the bars start at the bottom of the chartview, and in the old they started at the zero line.
i read that this was a bug in the old version and that it should look like this. Is it possible, to have the  buggy design back because i liked it, or is it not supposed to look like this?

i tried using axisMinimum = 0 but that only moved the zero from the yAxxis to the bottom.

```
    groupedBarChart.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
    groupedBarChart.chartDescription?.text = ""
    groupedBarChart.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.980, green:0.898, blue:0.498, alpha: 1.000)

    print(groupedBarChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum)

    groupedBarChart.fitBars = true
```

this is the code i use to customize the chart.

Im looking forward to your answers and thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of ios-charts you have used before update? What version you use now?

Comment: @AlexSmet i used charts version 3.0.2

Comment: can you please try `chartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.0` or do it for your right axis?

Comment: @AtalayAsa it only moves the zero line to the bottom.